# Set a random location on screen with a color

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Is there a way to change the color of a pixel in a specific location of the screen without having to add anything to existing layouts of activities/fragments?

An example use would be to display the application's fragment layout and change the color on a given location.

Comment: You can create a view on the fly, assign it a background color and render it to a defined position on the view.